# Impact of new top level domain extensions on SEO

Tags: seo, top-level-domains

I am planning to purchase a domain name for a hospital. I have a few options such as.

- namehospital.com
- namehospital.in (Hospital is in India)
- name.hospital

(Assuming the hospital's name is "name")

I want to know how these domains will impact the SEO. Should I go for "name.hospital"? will it have a significant impact on SEO?

Comment: If you use `namehospital.in` it will only rank in Google.in.  But it will probably rank better there than it would otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google use 200+ signals to rank website and domain name or extension will impact only 0.1%. Sometimes it hurts as well, if it look's spammy.

So Do you think you should gives more time on domain name rather than on other things?

Google main abstract is rank good quality website on top, and keyword in domain name is not a good factor to consider it. Will you consider that if you own any search engine?. Still Google may favor 0.1% if keyword is there on domain, but it is not future of good web, Google already giving less value on that with [time](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/251784203597910016) to [time](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/251789327691042816).

As stephen said, if you go with .in extension, then that site is more visible to Google.co.in because Google think this site is specific to Indian visitors only. You can also use [.com and use India as targeting option](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) in Google search console tool. Both will do same things. Regarding .hospital extension, then Google will [treat same as other TLD.](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html)

Comment: Sources for *domain name or extension will impact only 0.1%*?

Comment: Have you checked my all reference link in this article? The blog post said, it does not affect in ranking at all so no more webmaster do that and matt cutts status said, they have changed their algorithm because more spammer was using EMD. But still their is some benefits, because it is used to recognize brand website. And hence I said it does only 0.1%. I will link to patent when I'll find it.